# How to create table database and data saving into the table in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, custom-form

I want to add a table into the database and get input from a custom form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use ajax to get input data in the controller according to the instructions. happy code
[enter link description here](https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-create-insert-data-into-the-table-in-magento-2/)